# Characteristic polynomial of the differentiation map

Tags: linear-algebra

Determine the characteristic and minimum polynomial of the differentiation map $D:  \mathbb{R_n}[X]\longrightarrow \mathbb{R_n}[X]$ (where $\mathbb{R_n}[X]$ is a set of polynomials of degree at most $n$ with real coefficients).
$$$$ My attempt was to find a matrix of $f$ relative to the natural ordered basis {$1,X,X^2,...,X^n$} which is $$\pmatrix{0 & 1 & 0&...&0 \\ 0 & 0 & 2&...&0 \\: & : & :&...&:  \\0 & 0 & 0&...&n \\0 & 0 & 0&...&0 \\ }$$ hence, the characteristic polynomial turns to be $(-1)^{n+1}X^{n+1}$ while the original answer shows that it suppose to be  $(-1)^{n-1}X^{n-1}$. So where did I go wrong?
$$$$Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

$$\dim_{\Bbb R}\Bbb R_n[X]=n+1\implies\;\text{ the char. polynomial must be of degree}\;n+1$$

and this means "the original answer" is wrong.

Comment: Thank you very much! May I just ask is the minimum polynomial of the differentiation map $X^{n+1}$? So how it can be proven if not by observation? Thanks in advance.

Comment: but case like, $$\pmatrix{0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\0 & 0 & 0 & 3 \\0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ }$$ shows $A^{n+1}=A^4=0$ so, isn't it that the minimal polynomial is $X^{n+1}$?

Comment: Yes, you're right...and $\,A^n=A^3\neq 0\,$ , so the characteristic and minimal polynomial are the same. I forgot in my last comment that we were in dimension $\,n+1\,$ and with matrices $\,(n+1)\times (n+1)\,$ instead of $\,n\,$ . Thanks.

Comment: Thanks again for your help! Sorry for asking again, but how can I prove that the minimum polynomial of the differentiation map is $X^{n+1}$ without some private case?

Comment: Maybe the characteristic and minimum polynomial are NOT the same, because minimum polynomial can't have $-1$ as leading coefficient?

Comment: The leading coefficient can be $\,\pm 1\,$ , it all depends on the definition: for me, the car. polynomial is *always* $\,\det(xI-A)\,$ and **not** $\,\det(A-xI)\,$ , as many define. My way has the advantage that it **always** has positive leading coefficient...:)

Comment: Perhaps the easiest way to show that the min. pol. = char. pol. is to observe that $\,k<n\implies D^k\neq 0\,,\,\,\text{but}\;\;\,D^n=0\,$ ...:)

Comment: I am grateful to you for your help!

Comment: Any time, @proofy....